# Python variables with the same name not highlighted when selected one of them

Tags: python, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2017 in Python code, selecting a variable only highlights the selection and not the other occurrences of that variable in the code. How to change this behavior to highlighting the rest of the occurrences of the selected variable in Visual Studio Python projects?

Here is an example:

*Current behavior*

[image: current behavior]

*Desired behavior*

[image]

I believe this is a setting of IDE since in C# projects (where I actually took the second screenshot from) this functionality is working.

Comment: visual studio python syntax highlighting. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/editing-python-code-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: @DavidZemens I have read that article and it does not specify anything about highlighting the occurrences of the same variable. What am I missing?

Comment: just a suggestion (I haven't tried it). I'd be interested in the solution too because I have a lot of python code in a very large .SLN but basically I just use Visual Studio as a text editor for my py code, not an IDE.

Comment: The first `something` in the second line shouldn't be highlighted since it is an other (new) reference.